# Change syntax highlighting in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

I am using sublime color scheme for NetBeans and I really like colors, but there is one thing I don't like and I can't find where to change it. Been through all options in Tools->Options->Font and Colors, and still can't find it.

Here's screenshot:

### [image]

I want to change that highlight color to something else, since I can't see clear as it is.
Theme is from here: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plgin/51424/sublime-theme

Edit: It highlight class/id name when I click it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found solution after few hours of testing...

That's set under Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Then switch Language to Cascading Style Sheet.

Under Mark Occurrences is that highlight of Class/ID name i HTML (  doesn't matter if it's PHP  or HTML file )

Hope this helps someone, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

My only problem with that approach was that quoted text in PHP was still invisible when highlighted.

This is what worked for me:

Tools -> Options -> Fonts & Colors -> Higlighting

Then change to fixed (not inherited) foreground and background colors for highlighted text.